# Rails loop refactor

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have created a loop, to calculate a total rating of a record. To do this I am first looping through all the child records (ratings), extracting the rating from each row, adding it to the total and then outputting the total.

```
<% total = 0 %>
<% for ratings in @post.ratings %>
    <% total = (total + ratings.rating) %>
<% end %>
<%= total %>
```

My question is, simply, **Is this the rails way?**

It achieves the desired result, although needs 5 lines to do so. I am worried I am bring old habits from other languages into my rails project, and I am hoping someone could clarify if there is an easier way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following, preferably in the controller, will do it succinctly:

```
@rating = @post.ratings.sum { &:rating }
```

If that seems cryptic, you might prefer

```
@rating = @post.ratings.inject(0) { |sum, p| sum + p.rating }
```

Note, however, that this will fail if any of the ratings are null, so you might want:

```
@rating = @post.ratings.inject(0) { |sum, p| sum + (p.rating || 0) }
```

Comment: You can convert rating to_i explicitly to avoid || operator. But anyway - the first example is the only one you should accept - it reduces count of db queries to 1 and increase performance.

Answer (score 1):

You should generally keep logic out of your views. I would put that code in a helper or a controller, and the call a method to calculate the total

Answer (score 0):

Put the following in your controller, then you just need to use `@rating` in your view:

```
total = 0
@rating = @post.ratings.each { |r| total += r.rating }
```

Or you could move it into the Post model and do something like:

```
def self.total_rating
  total = 0
  ratings.each { |r| total += r.rating }
  total
end
```

and then simply call `@post.total_rating`